# Can I be notified when a post that I answered was edited?

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits, answers, notifications

Sometimes the OP change something significant in his question which affects my answer.

Is there some way I can be notified when:

A certain question was edited?
Question that I answered was edited?

Comment: The duplicate question is feature-request. Your question also seems to be a feature-request since the feature does not exist.

Comment: @hims056 - Does the fact that it's been 4 years enables to open this discussion again?

Comment: Since the duplicate question is exact what you want. It's worth to add bounty on the old question to start the discussion again. Which I have done. :)

Comment: I think that's a good idea, so I don't mind this question to be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can click the star under the vote-count. Then the question will appear in your profile under the "favorites" tab, and it will get highlighted every time there is activity in the question.

Not exactly the same as a notification, but at least you can monitor the activity.

Comment: I don't want to favorite all questions I answered.

Comment: ... and that is why I have ~6000 "favorite" questions...